# String formatting in Xpath expression

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

I have a function as follow. I need to find all the links with particular search term

```
def parse(search_term):
    response.xpath("//a[contains(.,search_term)]/@href").extract()
```

I believe above code gives me all the anchor links regardless of the search_term
If I replace search_term with "Energy" or any string, it gives perfect result for e.g

```
def parse(search_term):
    response.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Energy')]/@href").extract()
```

The above code gives me the links which has 'Energy' as text in it.
Is this a string formatting issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XPath expressions are regular Python strings, so you have to "interpolate" them explicitly:

```
def parse(search_term):
    response.xpath("//a[contains(.,'{}')]/@href".format(search_term)).extract()
```

Note that this only works for strings without any `'` characters on it -- if it does, you'll need some tricks to escape it.